# Supersingular vs non-singular (Same or different)

Tags: elliptic-curves, elliptic-curve-generation

I have a frustration for the term "supersingular" elliptic curve and "non-singular" elliptic curve.

In some paper, performance evaluation is done using supersingular elliptic curve and in some cases, they use non-singular elliptic curve. 
Are they same or different curves?

Answer (score 3):

Every elliptic curve is non-singular. Some elliptic curves are supersingular.

A quote from "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves" by Silverman, Remark V.3.2.2:

> Do not confuse the notions of singularity and supersingularity. A supersingular elliptic curve is, by definition, an elliptic curve, so it is nonsingular. The origin of the potentially confusing terminology is as follows. Historically, elliptic curves defined over $\mathbb{C}$ whose endomorphism rings are larger than $\mathbb{Z}$ were called singular, where "singular" was used in the sense of "unusual" or "rare". However, in this sense, all elliptic curves defined over $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p$ are singular! The endomorphism rings of most elliptic curves over $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p$ are order in imaginary quadratic fields. It is only the rare and unusual curve whose endomorphism ring is an order in a quaternion algebra, whence the term "supersingular".

Comment: It means all non-singular curve is not supersingular?

Comment: You beat me to it. I knew I had read a remark about that terminology somewhere...

Comment: @CurveEnthusiast. In some performance evaluation, they describe two using supersingular and another with non-singular. I don't know they are same or not.

Comment: @myat Read my statement carefully. An elliptic curve is non-singular by definition. There do not exist non-singular elliptic curves. Perhaps they meant non-supersingular, and just made a typo.

Comment: @CurveEnthusiast I have difficulties with the singular definition. E.g. an Edwards curve have singularities if I embed it in the projective plane.  Should I just have to look for singularities in the affine plane ?

Comment: @Ruggero An Edwards model indeed has singularities at infinity, and you do want to consider them (at least for the definition). Indeed, the model has singular points. However, for each curve there exists a non-singular model (note that singularity is really defined for a curve *model*, not really for a curve itself). For an Edwards curve, Galbraith shows it in his book as Lemma 9.12.18. Note that it is embedded in $\mathbb{P}^3$, and the arithmetic will probably not be as nice.